# Element on top of vertically centered div which does not leave the screen

Tags: html, css

I have a page with a vertically centered content area. On top of this, I want to have an image, which is relatively positioned to the centered element. I have this setup in a snippet.

```js
let i = 0;

function toggle() {
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.height = i++ % 2 === 0 ? '300px' : '600px';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.centered {
  background: #F00;
  width: 300px;
  position: relative;
}

.on-top {
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  bottom: 100%;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="centered">
    <img class="on-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      And some content. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle wrapper size</button>
```

This is working fine, until the height of `.wrapper` becomes to small (i.e. on mobile) so that the image on top flows out of view at the top.

So I want to have this layout, but once the image touches the top of wrapper (or body) I want to basically stick it there, so that it does not get cropped off / become completely invisible.

I know how to do this with JS, but would like to avoid running checks on resize. Is there any way to achieve this with pure HTML/CSS?

Comment: By height, did you mean width? When scaling it up and down in dev tools, height does not cause any issues, and it scrolls as expected, but width causes the image to overflow.

Comment: no, I mean height. The size you need to change is of .wrapper. I added a toggle button to show the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS grid to achieve this. I update the code slightly to make the image outside the centered container

```js
let i = 0;

function toggle() {
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').style.height = i++ % 2 === 0 ? '300px' : '600px';
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 600px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr auto 1fr;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: end;
}

.centered {
  background: #F00;
  width: 300px;
}

.on-top {
  margin-bottom: 16px;
}

button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <img class="on-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300x100">
  <div class="centered">
    <h1>Heading</h1>
    <p>
      And some content. Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen
      book.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="toggle()">toggle wrapper size</button>
```